# Extracting Unity3D package

Tags: 3d, extract, unity-game-engine

I got my hand on some Unity3D files, with the usual extension of *.unity3d .
I would like to know if I can extract them, if yes, how?

Header info:

UnityWeb 3.x.x 3.1.0

PS: I only want to extract the file(s) to get a model out of them. It would be very important for me (I want to make a real-life model of a game's parts, and I could not find a proper model anywhere else).

Comment: I don't understand. You've decompiled and now you want to convert to a 3d model? to any type in particular?  technically that may be possible but I don't think that legally is possible.  Also, do you want to do 3d printing or sculpture?  I ask you this, because at the end you'll probably end up with a super low-res model that won't fit your purposes.

Comment: I mean game models may look hi-res but it's a trickery of baking textures and mapping them to the lowest polygon model they can make.

Comment: I got the webplayer *.unity3d files, and I want to extract it's 3D models. To any type what 3DS max can handle. I don't care about legality, as I don't want to spread or something like that, it is for personal usage only, I won't even get cash from it (but spend a lot). I want to do it by hand, and as it has electronic parts too, I can't just "print" it. A low-res model is simply enough for a rough sketch about the stuff, and for some schematics (and sizing).

Comment: see if this tool is working for you, https://github.com/Perfare/AssetStudio

Answer (score 2):

.unity3d files (Also know as AssetBundles) are binary data, and cannot be extracted by conventional means. If you have a copy of Unity Pro, you can use the data inside of Unity ([Documentation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Unity3D Obfuscator can unpack a webbuild file (*.unity3d). The files that gets
unpacked are almost the same as in a standalone
build. All the assets (models, textures, sounds,
prefabs) are packed into .assets files and u can open .assets files from the free version of unity or unity pro then export the sound,textures,models,prefabs etc but i did not tried it yet. Im trying to know how to get the .unity3d files so i can extract music and models for personal...can u tell me how u did it?
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/51356-Unity-3D-Obfuscator-a-special-protection-tool-for-Unity-3D

Comment: Kind of strange that an obfuscator would have that type of functionality. Isn't the purpose of an obfuscator to make things *harder* to decompile?

Answer (score 0):

There's now also this tool (I wrote) which allows for unpacking .unitypackage files: http://upu.derfunk.com/.

You can contact me if you experience any issues.

Comment: The URL is dead.

Comment: Yeah, it's almost 10 years already. You can find the source here: https://github.com/derFunk/UPU - no guarantees that it's still working, I'm not using Unity anymore since quite some years.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install Unity 3D and import the package, that will give you access to all the files inside the package.

Comment: Doesn't work on free version of Unity 3D